# Sobolev spaces of $L^2$-type on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: hilbert-spaces

**DEFINITION**: Let $s\in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
H^{s}(ℝ)=\left\{f\in S'(\mathbb{R}):(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}, \hat{f} \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}) \right\}
$$

**OBSERVATION**: $f \in H^{s}(\mathbb{R})$ means that $\hat f$ is a measurable function. We introduce $||f||^{2}_{s}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(1+|\xi|^2)^{s}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^{2}d\xi = ||(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}\hat{f}||^{2}_{L^{2}}$, which comes from the scalar product $(f, g)_s=\int_\mathbb{R} (1+|\xi|^2)^s\hat{f}(\xi)\overline{\hat{g}(\xi)}d\xi$.

**PROPOSITION**: *$(H^s(\mathbb{R}), (.,.)_s)$ is a Hilbert Space*

*Proof.* $(.,.)_s$ is well-defined because if $f,g\in H^s(\mathbb{R})$, then
$$
(f, g)_s=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}\hat{f}(\xi)\overline{(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}\hat{g}(\xi))}d\xi \le||(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}\hat{f}||_{L^2}||(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}\hat{g}||_{L^2}\lt+\infty
$$
due to the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

So, what I'm trying to do is I want to prove the above proposition. And now I am stuck with it. Can anyone help me get this done? :-D

Comment: Let $T g(x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[ (1+|\xi|^2)^{-s/2} g](x)$ then $H^s = \{ Tg, g \in L^2\}$ with inner product $<Tg,Th>_{H^s} = <g,h>_{L^2}$ so this is by definition isomorphic to $L^2$.

Comment: So, if I'm not mistaken, the fact that $(.,.)_s$ is well defined, combined with the fact that $<Tg, Th>_{H^s} = <g,h>_{L^2}$ is isomorphic to $L^2$ completes the proof? (in which case, it's great! Thanks, btw)